# Encoding Error in sqlcontext.sqlfield id: IntegerType can not accept object u'1' in type <type 'unicode'>

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am getting error when extracting data from hive table and showing as below. Could someone help on this please

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3205: ordinal not in range(128)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import os
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark=SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
#sc=SparkContext()
# Creating Context        
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlcontext=SQLContext(sc)
# In[82]:
# filename=sys.argv[1]
df1 = spark.sql("select bdate,rawdata,rawdata1 from fraud_staging_1.stg_frc_fircohitdetails_1")
df1.show()
```